# Unable to edit spring stater

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Hi guys， I am trying to edit my spring starter in order to add more dependencies to my existing project, but I am getting this error:
**IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://start.spring.io/dependencies?bootVersion=2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT**

I appreciate your help!!!
[image]

Comment: Why do you use an old version and a SNAPSHOT version?

Comment: Because this project was created 4 years ago, and I want to modified it to add more functions

Comment: The project is using a SNAPSHOT version which is not stable nor does exist anymore. You have to switch to a stable version for example 2.3.0.RELEASE apart from the point that you should upgrade your project because there very long time no support anymore for such versions (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) Also you should show the pom file because I suppose there is something wrong in the pom file..

Comment: Thank you Khmarbaise, I upgraded the project and the issue is gone!